# Match backwards from a given word with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Using Javascript, I need to find an occurrence of a phrase in some text then match everything from it back to the last occurrence of a 5 digit number. (or at least thats the best way I know how to describe what I need)

**Consider the following text:**

---

24854

Random words

Ending Words

34975

Random words

Ending Words

**47593**

**Random words**

**Ending Words**

**Target Word**

32302

Random words

Ending Words

---

- Given the above, I'd like my regex to match Every thing from `47593` to `Target Word`.
- Each match should include both `47593` and `Target Word`
- It needs to be greedy in that there will be multiple matches in my actual text and I need them all returned in an array.

**This is what I've tried:** `.match(/[0-9]{5}[\s\S]+?Target Word/g)`

My problem (as always with these) is the new lines. In order to match across multiple lines, I'm using `[\s\S]` but doing so makes the regex match everything from the first 5 digit number to the first occurrence of `Target Word`

How can I change this to achieve the desired result? I'm thinking I need to use lookbehind but most examples I've found have been very confusing for me.

Comment: Maybe change `[\s\S]+?` to be `[\s\S]*` so that it's not greedy?

Comment: @Ian Yeah, tried that too, still matches from the first, thanks though

Comment: Sorry, I should've tried that in a fiddle (which I'm doing now)

Comment: @Ian `[\s\S]+?` is lazy

Comment: @Spooky Right, but I thought it might act lazy in a different way than `*` - I'm not sure why I thought that though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use negative lookahead,

```
[0-9]{5}(?:(?![0-9]{5})[\S\s])*?Target\s*Word
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sX9fR0/9)

The above negative lookahead `(?:(?![0-9]{5})[\S\s])*` asserts that after the 5 digit number, match any space or non-space character zero or more times but it must not be a 5 digit number.

Comment: Sorry that was me, my hand slipped when trying to accept your answer (which it wont let me do for 5 more minutes), this worked for me, Thank you!

Comment: I voted mine back up, not sure where the other one came from or why, weird

Answer (score 1):

if there are no 5 digit pattern in the random words, you may perhaps use

```
/([\d]{5}(?:[^\d]{5})+?Target Word)/gm
```

[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nL6pR9/4)

Comment: unfortunately, `Random words` can contain just about any character including new lines

Comment: I didn't downvote, but how about using `\d` in your first character class?

Comment: @DelightedD0D updated for the same, I hope it is not possible to match  a 5 digit pattern in the random words.

Comment: @pushpraj actually the 5 digit number will really be more complex than that. I just made this as a simple example to illustrate my need.

Comment: Whose downvote is this? Care to explain? This answer would be valid in other situations. Therefore, this answer may help those with a similar problem, albeit one which fits the criteria given at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I kida wish downvoting required at least a remark...how helpful can it be to kick someone and walk away without a word as to why?

Comment: That regex passes your test because the number of characters between `47593` and `Target Word` happens to be a multiple of five, and none of them are digits.  Add one space, or change one of the letters to a digit, and it fails.  The "captive lookahead" technique that [Avinash used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25589646/20938) seems horribly complex, but it's the simplest solution (in JavaScript, anyway).